# Nissan Versa 2014 reverse light wire

Tags: nissan, headlight, wiring, backup-camera, versa

I have a backup camera to set up, but checking which wires go to which light isn't easy since the bulbs are mounted onto a circuit board instead of visually being able to see where the wires go. Upon a little research I see that other models use the yellow wire for the reverse bulb. I imagine that the black one is ground but I would like to make sure before I mess with the wiring.

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to back probe the yellow wire to see if it's the one you need. I have used a needle attached to an alligator clip on a wire as my probe mechanism. Works pretty slick without damaging anything. Just set the emergency brake before you do anything.

Comment: I thought of doing that just not with a needle. Would you say the black is in fact ground?

Comment: It is more than likely the ground, but you can back probe that as well, using an ohmmeter to see if there is continuity to a known ground source. Do this with the vehicle off. You'll have to check the other with the vehicle on, of course.